# ZPL Center image within a Graphic box

Tags: image, centering, zpl

I have logos of various sizes. I am trying to center them on a label within a ^GB
Is this possible or is there another way of doing this?

Code I tried: ^FO10,295,2^GB585,90^GFA,{items.manufacturer_logo}^FS

Answer (score 0):

The ^GB command is used to draw boxes, not to print graphic fields and the parameters you put after the GB command are the width (585) and height (90) of the box.

Regarding the graphic field (^GF), there isn't a parameter in this field you can use to align to the center the image, so you need to manually enter the coordinates to center the field in the ^FO command, but if you're working on a software which can dinamically calculate the position of the fields, you can maybe do it automatically.

When it comes to design a label in ZPL language, my advice is usually to use zebradesigner, create the label and then export it using the "[print to file](https://www.thezcorner.com/printers/software/printers-print-to-file-option-in-zebradesigner-3)" option you can find in the print view.
You can download zebradesigner for free from here
https://www.zebra.com/gb/en/support-downloads/printer-software/zebra-designer-3-downloads.html

Comment: This is nice if all the manufacturers logos were the same size. We have set the height of each, it is the width that is causing all the problems. Don't want to create labels for each manufacturer :(

Comment: have you considered to use zebranet bridge? it has a feature (in the Tools menu) which allows to edit the graphic files and convert them into zpl code you can then store on the printer memory and recall on the labels or directly insert into your labels. https://www.zebra.com/gb/en/support-downloads/printer-software/zebranet-bridge-enterprise.html

Comment: Find the largest logo, and note the width. Make all the rest of the logos the same width, by adding additional white space to them. If you want them centered, add equal amounts on each side of the logo. In the end, all your logos will be the same width, and you will have no problems.